# App crashes after installing "AudioKit" with error dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib

Tags: ios, audiokit

After installing "AudioKit" using pod, Xcode returns following error and crashes the App.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/62644586-FCA6-43ED-8DCC-488BC1436AD5/myApp.app/myApp
Reason: image not found
```

**Tried solutions:**

- Clean and build
- Clean derived data
- Runpath Search Paths (LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS)

  - In the example project, these are determined by the cocoapod, but each one is set to $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks
- Dynamic Library Install Name (LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME)

  - In the example project, this is unchanged from the default $(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)
- Dynamic Library Install Name Base (DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE)

  - In the example project, set to @rpath (again determined by the Cocoapod)
- Always Embeded Swift Standard Libraries to **TRUE**
- Build Phases > Embed Frameworks -> swiftStdLib's

Comment: Is your app linked with AVFoundation?

Comment: Yes! I have already added that, It keep requesting to add each and every ".dylib" to embeded binaries.